# I am confused about Encapsulation in Java

Tags: java, encapsulation

I looked into encapsulation many times, but still I'm not 100% clear about this topic.

My questions are:

What does getter really do? Say I only use getter but don't use setter, what will happen?

And same for setter. What does it really do, and how it manages to access private variable? If I only use setter but don't use getter, what will happen?

And also we have constructors in a class:

```
class Car {
     int x;
     Car(int x) {
        this.x = x;
     }
}
```

For me, it seems like constructor does the same thing as setter, although i "know" that it doesn't. Therefore, I wanted a clarification for this as well.

Comment: It's very simple: a getter method just returns the value of a member variable, and a setter sets the value of a member variable. The constructor in your example sets the value of a member variable, just like a setter method, but it does it on a new `Car` object instead of on an existing `Car` object.

Comment: What do you mean by "existing Car object"? Where does it exist if i haven't created one?

Comment: @jjavid what he meant is, it's only used once on one object. You wont use it again on same object, it'll be another object. `Car c1 = new Car();` `Car c2 = new Car();`

Comment: Oh okay. But then what about setter?

Comment: as for setter, anytime we need to set it's value, we use it. `c1.set(5)`, if we need to change its value again `c1.set(3)`, so on whenever you need to change `c1.x` value, use setter.

Comment: wouldn't we automatically set it when we write `Car c1 = new Car(5);`, and then to change it we can write `c1.set(3)` ?

Comment: yeah, but you can also do `Car c1 = new Car();`, it's constructor overloading concept.

Comment: regarding my other question, can i use setter without getter? and if so, then what would be the purpose of only using setter? same goes for getter

Comment: You can, but the problem is anytime you are required of the data member `x` for anything, you will have to create a function in that respective class `Car`, which is not really optimal.

Comment: and without setter, you'll be able to set its value *only once* through constructor. You won't be able to change it later.

Comment: but i can use c1 = new Car(3); and change it's value. How is it only once?

Comment: What if you have multiple data members, let's say `a, b,c,d,..z` , are you going to do `c1 = new car(1,2,3,...26)` ??? just to change the value of one data member?

Comment: `setter` you can actually specify which data member you cant to change. `setA(int a){ this.a=a; }` `setB(int b){ this.b=b; }` likewise for other data member as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulation is controlling access to specific values using access modifiers.  Consider the following:

```
class Foo {
public int v;
  public Foo(int v) {
     this.v = v;
  }
}
```

Now let an instance be created, `Foo f = new Foo(20);`  One can access v simply by doing `f.v`.  And it can be changed by doing `f.v = 30;`

But what I for some reason `v` should be stored in a list or a string.  You can't change it since it will break the class for existing users.  So that is where getters come in.

```
class Foo {
private String v;
   public Foo(int v) {
     this.v = v+"";
   }
   public int getV() {
     return Integer.parseInt(v);
  }
}
```

The above is highly contrived but it illustrates that the internal handling of a value may be altered without affecting the user interface to access that value.  So by using getters (and setters), one can do the following:

- ensure that the user interface consistently returns the expected value without regard to its internal nature.
- allows the user to set a value within specific limits. So a setter could enforce limitations on the value before accepting it.
- making defensive copies to protect altering the internal values. E.g Don't return an array as one could make changes to the array as it is stored in the instance.  Just return a copy of the array (or any other data structure for that matter).

Imo, encapsulation is closely related to abstraction in that abstraction hides implementation details of how things are done.  Encapsulation hides and/or protects methods and variables by imposing some form of access control.

Answer (score 1):

private - only makes it accessible within the class. Let's assume the following class:

```
class Car {
     private int x;
     Car(int x){
         this.x = x;
     }
     public int get(){
          return this.x;
     }
     public void set(int x){
          this.x = x;
     }
}
```

now another class and you create an instance of class `car`

```
class Car2 {
     public static void main(String args[]){
        Car c = new Car();
        c.x = 5; // Do you think this will work?
        int a = c.x; // this too?
    }
}
```

(spoiler)It won't since it's private.
That's why we use functions(getter and setter) to access those private data members.
Constructor can function same as setter, but the difference is, values will be assigned at the time of object creation. 
Example:
`Car c = new Car(5);`
When the object `c` is being created, it's data member `x` will be assign a value `5`.

Comment: so for a setter, value won't be assigned at the time of object creation? Because, as in this example, if we assign 5 to x, then immediately we will set 5 in this.x = x. I didn't get how that's different.

Comment: that means, after the creation the object, we will be assigning value, not when the time of creation.

Comment: think of constructor as naming an unborn baby(pregnant) and setter as naming after giving birth.

Comment: I think i got it. When we do `Car c = new Car(5);`, then it assigns it immediately, but when we do it with a setter, it will happen afterwards. Is this true?